# Different behaviour of waitKey() in Windows and Linux

Tags: c++11, gcc, mingw, opencv3.0

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image(200, 200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
    namedWindow("Displayimage", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Displayimage", image);

    int key = -1;
    while (key!=27) {
        key = waitKey(0);
        cout << key << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run it on Windows (CodeBlocks + minGW) and press "Shift" -> nothing happens and give different codes for "a" and "A" --> Good

When I run it on Linux/Ubuntu (CodeBlocks + GCC) and press "Shift" -> it returns a code for the Shift key and does not allow me to press "SHIFT+a". It always return the same code for "a" and "A".

Do you have any idea?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the *cv::waitKey(int)* function is quite dependent on the underlying UI framework. For windows OS, common window display frameworks include .Net, QT and MFC. While in Linux distributions, the window display frameworks usually include GTK, QT, VTK and etc. You can find different versions of *waitKey(int)* implementations is the *highgui* module of OpenCV source, and the *gtk* version seems not to handle keystrokes combination, it's handled by using *GMutex*. So if you want to handle key combinations, you might have to change your UI framework or modify the implementation, and recompile your OpenCV with the selected UI framework.